# Subtypes in GraphQL mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am attempting to specify a subtype in a graphql mutation
Using AWS Amplify and AWS AppSync.

```
mutation CreatePhoneType {
  createPhoneType(input: {
    desc: "Mobile Phone"
  }) {
    id
    desc
  }
}

mutation CreatePhone {
  createPhone(input: {
    number: "+91 704-011-2342",
    phonetype: { id: "f6b3c538-378a-48d1-a264-96dfef4472a4" }    
  }) {
    id
    number,
    phonetype {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the schema definition:

```
type Phone @model {
  id: ID!
  number: AWSPhone!
  phonetype: PhoneType
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime
}

type PhoneType @model {
  id: ID!
  desc: String!
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime
}
```

I'm attempting to insert a new phone value. The Phone type has a subtype of PhoneType. I've created the PhoneType successfully and would like to reference the existing phone type as part of a mutation to create a Phone value. I've tried specifying the ID! but that does not work. How can you specify an existing subtype when creating a new value in a GraphQL mutation?
I've checked the GraphQL docs but there is not a lot of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `@connection` to generate the related type.

So Phone should be:

```
type Phone @model {
  id: ID!
  number: AWSPhone!
  phonetype: PhoneType @connection
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime
}
```

Once you do this, a generated type is available to reference.

So this now works:

```
mutation CreatePhone {
  createPhone(input: {
    number: "+91 704-011-2342",
    phonePhonetypeId: "f6b3c538-378a-48d1-a264-96dfef4472a4"  
  }) {
    id
    number
  }
}
```